# why ethereum can run so much process with level db at the same time?

Tags: leveldb

Leveldb can only run at single process.

why Ethereum can run p2p, create block, rpc server at the same time, and the leveldb no lock?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leveldb/7WyCMZ3egOo

Answer (score 1):

All the modules you mention: p2p, blocks, rpc, etc, are executed inside a unique process: `geth`.

Inside `geth` the different modules have access to leveldb synchronized through mutexes and other synchronization primitives like locks.

Answer (score -1):

When you run a key-value-store like levelDb, the bottleneck is not the CPU-usage but the disc-IO. So it does not matter if you use 1 or more processes to handle the sets and gets, but mostly the speed of the hard-drive is relevant.

Comment: This doesn't answer how geth access to leveldb.